# How Can I represent a "global" Enum in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, enums

I have something like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Mercedes'),
        (2, 'Audi'),
        (3, 'BMW'),
    )

    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Now I want to filter the cars in another context (not inside this model), what is the best way?

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(car_type=????)
```

Someone knows if is possible to have a global constant? and filter like this:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(car_type=mercedes)
```

Or, another way...

Comment: Can't you just type it as a string?  `cars = Car.objects.filter(car_type='Mercedes')` or import Car and do it: `cars = Car.objects.filter(car_type=Car.TYPE_CHOICES[0][1])`

Comment: Would be nice, but if the name of the car changes? I have to change everywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Car(models.Model):
    TYPE_MERCEDES = 1
    TYPE_AUDI = 2
    TYPE_BMW = 3

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (TYPE_MERCEDES, 'Mercedes'),
        (TYPE_AUDI, 'Audi'),
        (TYPE_BMW, 'BMW'),
    )

    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

And to filter you use:

```
Car.objects.filter(car_type=Car.TYPE_MERCEDES)
```